# GWT - internationalization, the default works but when I add locale to URL I still get the default values. Any idea?

Tags: gwt, internationalization, locale

I have now seriously started experimenting with GWT, and I am stuck of course. I am trying with a very simple internationalization and when I add locale to my URL as following it doesn't work and always default data is fetched.

```
http://127.0.0.1:8888/DoTime.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997&locale=sv_SE
```

In the following picture you can see structure of the project. The name of the application is "DoTime".

[image: Folder structure]

In the file **/client/properties/DoTimeConstants_sv_SE.properties** I have

```
localeTest = Vi skriver något på svenska för att testa om vi kan få det på svenska med locale.
appTitle = DoTime på svenska
```

In the corresponding file **/client/DoTimeConstants** I have

```
package com.dotime.client;
import com.google.gwt.i18n.client.Constants;
    public interface DoTimeConstants extends Constants {

    @DefaultStringValue("haha we are writing something in default to test locale")
    String localeTest();

    @DefaultStringValue("DoTime default title")
    String appTitle();
}
```

I the file **/client/properties/DoTimeMessages_sv_SE.properties** I have

```
@DefaultMessage("''{0}'' is not a valid symbol.")
  String invalidSymbol(String symbol);

  @DefaultMessage("Last update: {0,date,medium} {0,time,medium}")
  String lastUpdate(Date timestamp);
```

In the corresponding file **/client/DoTimeMessages** I have

```
package com.dotime.client;

import com.google.gwt.i18n.client.Messages;
import java.util.Date;

public interface DoTimeMessages extends Messages {
    @DefaultMessage("''{0}'' en symbol på svenska.")
    String invalidSymbol(String symbol);

    @DefaultMessage("Senaste uppdatering: {0,date,medium} {0,time,medium}")
    String lastUpdate(Date timestamp);
}
```

In the file **DoTime.gwt.xml** I have add locale="sv_SE" and added inherit I18N:

```
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Google Inc.//DTD Google Web Toolkit 2.0//EN"
        "http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/releases/2.0/distro-source/core/src/gwt-module.dtd">
<module rename-to="DoTime">

    <!-- Inherit the core Web Toolkit stuff.                  -->
    <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User'/>

    <!-- Specify the app entry point class.                   -->
    <entry-point class='com.dotime.client.DoTime'/>

    <inherits name="com.google.gwt.i18n.I18N"/>

    <extend-property name="locale" values="sv_SE"/>

    <!-- Specify the app servlets.                   -->
    <servlet path='/DoTimeService' class='com.dotime.server.DoTimeServiceImpl'/>

</module>
```

In my entry point method I fetch appTitle which returns the default value correctly

```
String appTitle = constants.appTitle();
```

but when I change my url by adding &locale=sv_SE nothing happens and I still have the default value.

I did try first by only having locale file extension locale=sv without any luck and later changed to sv_SE but it didn't work anyway. What is it I am missing? Do you have any idea? Many thanks for some clues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your properties files must be name the exact same as the `Constants` or `Messages` interfaces, except for the locale suffix and file extension. Specifically here, they must be in the same package; you cannot put them in some other package (the `properties` subpackage in this case) and expect GWT to find them.

---

Side notes:

- I think the locale in the `gwt.xml` and in the URL has to be written in the Java notation, using a dash as separator rather than an underscore.
- you shouldn't use the `<servlet>` tag in your `gwt.xml`; they're used by the `GWTTestCase` runtime, but then you'd rather make a test-specific module that `<inherits>` your app module, rather than put those declarations in your app module.

Comment: absolutely right. I moved the property files to the same package as interfaces and locale worked immediately. Many thanks.